# Basic delay command for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need a wait command in Visual Basic that suits me.

I know:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal milliseconds As Long)
sleep 5000
```

But that makes the program unresponsive.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) 'The window doesn't load until the timing is over (useless)
```

My code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32 'To check if is 64Bit or 32Bit

Public Class Loading
  Private Sub Loading_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0").GetValue("Identifier").ToString.Contains("x86") Then
      My.Settings.Is64 = False
    Else
      My.Settings.Is64 = True
    End If

    'I need command here

    If My.Settings.Is64 = True Then
      Form64.Show()
      Me.Close()
    Else
      MsgBox("No version developed for 32-bit computers.")
      End
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Errors:

@Idle_Mind

```
1. function 'OnInitialize' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.
2.  'MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime' is not a member of 'App.Loading.MyApplication'.
    3.  'OnInitialize' is not a member of 'Object'.
```

Comment: Of course the window doesn't load. You've told the thread loading it to take a five second nap. :-) Can you [edit] to explain what you're trying to accomplish with that delay? (You posted the `Loading` code, but there's no call to `Sleep` there. Where would you be using it? And why?) If we know what you're trying to do, we can probably help find an answer for you.

Comment: So you want to run something after 5 seconds whilst keeping the UI responsive? A timer? That looks for a 64bit *processor* is that correct? Why not environment.is64bitoperatingsystem

Comment: FYI, if you're using .NET 4.0+, you can figure out the environment with just [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a splash screen?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, I'm doing a splash screen.

Comment: @KenWhite Same as above.

Comment: @Cory That only detects the program's bit environment doesn't it? I want the system environment.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm not using the wait to search the processor bit (splash screen). And environment only detects the program. Inaccurate for my needs.

Comment: @BrandonNguyen: `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` detects the OS environment; `Environment.Is64BitProcess` detects whether the current process is 64-bit.

Answer (score 7):

From the comments:

[image]

Go into Project Properties and leave your main form as the Startup form.  Set your splash screen form as the splash screen entry down at the bottom.  Now click the "View Application Events" button to the right and override `OnIntialize` so you can set the [MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.minimumsplashscreendisplaytime?view=netframework-4.8) like this:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize(ByVal commandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)) As Boolean
            ' Set the display time to 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds). 
            Me.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 5000
            Return MyBase.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs)
        End Function

    End Class


End Namespace
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute the rest of your code after 5 seconds, why not create a separate thread/task, which will wait for 5 seconds and then trigger the rest of your code to run via a callback to the main thread? This approach will not hang your UI.

**EDIT:** If you want a splash screen, drop a Timer control, set the interval to 5 seconds and run the rest of your code inside a Tick event handler.

Assuming you have already set up the Timer, move your loading code into `Timer1_Tick` handler:

```
Public Class Loading
  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'part 1
    If Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0").GetValue("Identifier").ToString.Contains("x86") Then
      My.Settings.Is64 = False
    Else
      My.Settings.Is64 = True
    End If

    'part 2
    If My.Settings.Is64 = True Then
      Form64.Show()
      Me.Close()
    Else
      MsgBox("No version developed for 32-bit computers.")
      End
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Or leave part 1 in `Load`, and move part 2 into `Tick`. I would prefer this option for semantics.

Also don't forget to set `Timer.Enabled = True`.

Comment: @BrandonNguyen: First or second part? Second part should be very simple to do. Did you try implementing it this way? Where did you stumble?

Comment: Second part. I have a timer and set the interval.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a place to CANCEL the application, you use the [Application.Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4zch4d2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event and set `e.Cancel = True` from within there.  When this is done the main form will not even appear; the application will simply exit.  That could look something like:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            If someCondition Then
                MessageBox.Show("oops")
                e.Cancel = True ' <-- main form will NOT show, app will simply exit
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class


End Namespace
```

Comment: +1. Yeah, this would probably make more sense. Why wait 5 seconds to only discover the app is not supported on your system?

Answer (score 1):

just do this:

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 500
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Next
```

Edit: Be careful with DoEvents; it can cause problems if the user clicks on something or an event is processed when it shouldn't. See  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html

Comment: [`DoEvents` is bad](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html), avoid using it if you can.

Comment: @Neolisk Sure, but I still use it because it's much simpler. Setting up a background thread to handle the waiting would definitely be better especially if you expect the user to do anything other than just look at the screen.

Comment: -1. I'd add a second downvote if I could for "I know DoEvents is bad, but I still use it because it's much simpler, and advise others to do so as well." - Bad advice.

Comment: @KenWhite Hey this guy is doing a splash screen; with no buttons to click, I don't see any problems with DoEvents here. However... I realize you've been programming since the early days of dBASE III+, working in dBASE, FoxPro, Clipper, C, C++, x86 assembler, and Delphi (among others).  You're a veteran of the US Air Force; Bravo! You co-authored a Delphi/C++Builder function and component library (Clipper Functions for Delphi, or CFD). You even wrote one of the early QuickBooks API applications. Not to mention your 52k reputation on this site. I get your point and will be careful in the future.

Comment: What does my profile have to do with anything? Using `DoEvents` means it's not just the splash screen that can be clicked on and can respond, and advising its use (particularly to new users who might not understand the problems it can cause) is bad advice. There's no need to get personal here; I downvoted your answer, not you the person.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite I used your profile only to show my respect for you as a person. I have a lot to learn from you. Here is a link that informed me on the DoEvents issues: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html

Answer (score 0):

Since sleeping and busy waiting are generally frowned upon, you could do something with an `AutoResetEvent`:

```
Private ReadOnly _resetEvent As AutoResetEvent = New AutoResetEvent(False)

Sub Pause(ByVal milliseconds As Long)
    Dim waitInterval As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds)
    While Not _resetEvent.WaitOne(waitInterval)
         ' Waiting!
    End While
End Sub
```

This is not recommended, but here's an example using the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
Sub Pause(ByVal milliseconds As Long)
    If milliseconds <= 0 Then Return
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Dim i As Long = 0
    Do
        If i Mod 50000 = 0 Then ' Check the timer every 50,000th iteration
            sw.Stop()
            If sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= milliseconds Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                sw.Start()
            End If
        End If
        i += 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

And then where you need to pause, just call this `Pause()` method:

```
Pause(5000) ' Pause for 5 seconds
```

Comment: I am guilty of this, but everything I have come across says that busy waiting is a no-no. I have however not found a better way to give some buffer time in between (for example) loading html items, and those items pulling from the DB onto the page.